# Wildcard instantiated List does not accept value

Tags: java, generics

I don't get why it's not okay to put a String into the List below:

```
        List<? extends Comparable<String>> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        String string = "A";
        test.add(string); // why is this not ok? in fact "String" should be a subype of "? extends Comparable<String>
```

Can anyone please explain where the problem is? I know that there is no benefit in having a wildcard at this point because we can't inherit from "String", but I want to understand what's happening an why the compiler is complaining about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```java
class X implements Comparable<String> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(String o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
List<? extends Comparable<String>> test = new ArrayList<X>();
```

Does it make sense to add a `String` to `test`?

Comment: Of course not! Thanks! Got it ;)
I thougth that it would be ok, because "test" is instantiated with "ArrayList<String>" what defacto makes it a "List<String>".

Comment: @SailingBytes When you declare the type as `List<? extends Comparable<String>>`, the compiler will treat it as a List of some (unknown) type that implements `Comparable<String>`. The exact type of the value assigned to it no longer matters.